# php tcpdf writeHTML() fail when using <sometext>

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to export some data to pdf and it works almost fine.

If my content has `<some text>` in it (and some text IS NOT an html tag) the pdf loses the styling up to this point and is corrupted.

How can I fix this?

Comment: So something like `<p>This is <some text></p>` would fail? But `<p>This is some text</p>` would not?

Comment: yes. it seems that the code try to evaluate the <some text> as if it was an html tag and fails

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF is very picky about input HTML. It supports a limited subset of HTML and all other tags are stripped. Last time I checked, TCPDF uses `strip_tags` to remove the unsupported tags (and *anything* that looks like tags). As such, there's a solid chance that depending on the particulars of your input it may remove more than just the tag-looking text in some cases.

Let's take this example:

```
<p>This is <some text></p>
```

In the browser `<some text>` would be treated like a tag with an empty "text" attribute, and not be visible to the user. TCPDF is indeed basically treating it the same way. I looked for a reliable automated fix for this, but most HTML parsers treat it the same way. The [Tidy extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) outright removes it for instance.

If you need those greater-than and less-than symbols in your text, they need to be encoded as HTML entities. For example, it needs to be passed to TCPDF like this:

```
<p>This is &lt;some text&gt;</p>
```

One possible solution is to run expected plaintext (that is, sources that aren't expected to contain any HTML) through `htmlspecialchars` before adding it to your HTML. This will encode those special HTML characters into entities.

For example, a user's form entry into a field:

```
$someusertext = $_POST['somefield'];
$html = '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($someusertext, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</p>';
```